# Given an MD5 hash find the libc it corresponds to

Tags: 12.04, glibc

I'd like to find the Ubuntu distribution that contains a libc.so.6 file that hashes to a particular MD5 hash value. Is there a way to go about doing that?

Comment: Can you post the hash here?

Answer (score 0):

Download all the versions of the files, and check their contents. There is file called md5sums, containing md5sum.

```
7e94b12ee1619d53abd5cbbfb7bb3cca  usr/lib/gconv/ISO-2022-JP.so
```

You can find the packages here:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6